# How do I set default database in the SQLite shell?

Tags: sqlite

Using SQLite3, I start the DBMS using `sqlite3 testDB.db`, which sets `testDB.db` as the default database, i.e., the database is assumed when not specified explicitly in SQL statements.

How do I switch default database to another one? Do I have to restart `sqlite3`?

Comment: SQLite 3 is a library. `sqlite3` is a command-line shell (that uses that library). Which one do you intend to use?

Comment: Sorry, I intend to use the `sqlite3` shell interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite> .help
...
.open ?--new? ?FILE?   Close existing database and reopen FILE
                         The --new starts with an empty file
...
```

Alternatively, you can [attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) multiple databases:

> Tables in an attached database can be referred to using the syntax *schema-name.table-name*. If the name of the table is unique across all attached databases and the main and temp databases, then the *schema-name* prefix is not required. If two or more tables in different databases have the same name and the *schema-name* prefix is not used on a table reference, then the table chosen is the one in the database that was least recently attached.

So you can change the "default" by making another database the most recently attached one (just detach it and re-attach it again).

Comment: What if I wanted mutiple open databases, but just wanted to switch without closing one of them?